# Pass variable in curl to send message to slack

Tags: bash, curl, slack

I'm trying to send a message to slack using the curl command. I wanted to use a variable in the curl command

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data '{"text": $text }' "https://hooks.slack.com/services/blabla"
```

here the $text refers to the text I want to send.

this is how $text looks like

```
text="The following jobs are in queue: $jobs"
```

If you try echo'ing thext, it will be something like

```
echo $text
The following jobs are in queue: "job1" "job2"
```

But the above curl command is giving **invalidpaylod**

Comment: Use `'{ "text": "'"$text"'" }'` instead. If the text may contain characters that has to be encoded, use [tag:jq] to generate the data (e.g.: `data=$(jq -n --arg text "$text" '{$text}')`) and use it in the curl invocation like `curl ... --data "$data" ...`

Answer (score 4):

You have the text variable in single quotes and so the content won't be expanded. Put single quotes around the variable:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data '{"text": '$text' }' "https://hooks.slack.com/services/blabla"
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is resulting in the following error
Could not resolve host: following
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: jobs
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: are
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: in
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: queue